# Differentiating the "device" calendar from online calendar services when asking the user to add an event

Tags: user-behavior, terminology, users, calendar, multiple-devices

I have an event for users that they can add to their calendar. So, users are given multiple options of which calendar program or service they want to add the event to. However I am having trouble explaining to the users which option they should pick.

For example, the users can add the event to:

- Their device calendar, such as Outlook, Apple Mail, Mail for iOS, Mail for Android, etc (This is just an .ics file which is the same between typical local mail software)
- Google mail (which requires a specially formatted link)
- Office 365 (which also requires a specially formatted link)
- (any number of other online services)

The issue is, what is a better way of presenting the "device" calendar to the users? I doubt many users know what a device calendar is. It is difficult (if not impossible) to predict what calendar software they are using.

Here is an idea of what I am working with. The "add to calendar" icon reveals the choices below it:

[image: Example]

Comment: "Device" is growing usage, but I agree not everybody understands it immediately. While reading your post, I wondered whether "local" (whatever local software is used) vs. "cloud" (but don't use that term!) is the distinction you want to make?

Answer (score 2):

Eventbrite does it well, and I never had an issue with the clarity:

[image]

I think thats a good place to start, on clicking of the "add to calendar" button it would release the dropdown with options.